# Magento 2.4 installation on DrupalVM

Tags: magento2.4

I want to install Magento 2.4 so I followed the steps from [devdocs.magento.com](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/install-quick-ref.html).

After running below command, Show successfully installed.
`bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://www.mage2.test --db-host=localhost --db-name=mage2_dev --db-user=root --db-password=root --admin-firstname=admin --admin-lastname=admin --admin-email=admin@admin.com --admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --language=en_US --currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --use-rewrites=1`

But when I run below command gives error as attached
`php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer`

[image]

when I am going to login to admin panel after using username and password, it is giving configure 2 factor authorization to proceed to admin area as per screenshot :

[image]

When I tried to uninstall 2 factor authorization with command `bin/magento module:disable Magento_TwoFactorAuth`, it is giving below error

[image]

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It usually happens when you have your instance in use, you can put the store in maintenance mode before do it.

```
bin/magento maintenance:enable \
&& bin/magento module:disable Magento_TwoFactorAuth
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried your approach. Maintenance mode is enabled but still facing same issue to disable the module Magento_TwoFactorAuth.